# Powershell Import-Module command doesn't work with c# api

Tags: c#, powershell, virtual-machine

Import-Module command work fine with powershell windows console but same command doesn't work on c# api.
i'm using this project for execute powershell script: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C

it execute many of them commands but it doesn't execute "Import-Module 'c:\vm\vm.psd1'" command. i try import microsoft modules but it doesn't work too. How can i execute "Import-Module" command with c# api?

Also `add-pssnapin 'virtualmachinemanager'`  doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

Try load module in this way:

```
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
powerShell.Commands.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddParameter("Name", "c:\vm\vm.psd1'");
```

or

```
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
powershell.Commands.AddCommand("Add-PsSnapIn").AddParameter("Name", "virtualmachinemanager");
```

With a pipeline try create an `InitialSessionState`

```
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
           iss.ImportPSModule(new string[] { @"C:\vm\vm.psd1"});
           Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
           runSpace.Open();
```

then use your code with `pipeline` to run cmdlet from module loaded

Comment: pipeline.Commands.Add return void. i use such as `Command cmd = new Command("Import-Module");
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("Name", @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012\Virtual Machine Manager\bin\psModules\virtualmachinemanager\virtualmachinemanager.psd1"));
            pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);
` but it doesn't work too.

Comment: @Baris I'm sorry, it works on `Powershell` Class.. not in a `pipeline` object. Add other solution.

Comment: thanks for answer but how do i use PowerShell class? i use only pipeline for execute commands. i try use PowerShell class such as before run script:  `PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.Commands.AddCommand("Import-Module")
              .AddParameter("Name",
                            @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012\Virtual Machine Manager\bin\psModules\virtualmachinemanager\virtualmachinemanager.psd1");
            ps.Invoke();` but it doesn't work. how do i use it?

Comment: @Baris have you tried with `InitialSessionState` and `pipeline` as in my last example in answer? Should works!

Comment: Thanks i tired `InitialSessionState` but it doesn't work too. maybe i will should re-install system center virtual machine manager.

Comment: @Baris I can't test it with virtualmachinemanager but with others module works fine.I Can't help more of that. Remeber to add code by editing your answer and not here in comments. Thanks.

Comment: i test with other microsoft's modules but i can't import any modules. Thank you for your helps. i'm new in here, if i need add code to comment, i will edit my question from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this for loading the snapin and executing your commands:

```
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

//...

var rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
using (var myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig))
{
    PSSnapInException snapInException = null;
    var info = rsConfig.AddPSSnapIn("FULL.SNAPIN.NAME.HERE", out snapInException);

    myRunSpace.Open();
    using (var pipeLine = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline())
    {
        Command cmd = new Command("YOURCOMMAND");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("PARAM1", param1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("PARAM2", param2);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("PARAM3", param3);

        pipeLine.Commands.Add(cmd);
        pipeLine.Invoke();
        if (pipeLine.Error != null && pipeLine.Error.Count > 0)
        {
            //check error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answer. i try add snapin but i didn't add snapin anywise.